# count query using eloquent relation laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, aggregate, relationship

I have three tables called `category`, `subcategory` and `product` .

`category` has

```
id       category_name
```

`subcategory` has

```
id      category_id     sucategory_name
```

and `product` table has

```
id     category_id      subcategory_id      productname
```

now what i want is, i want to get the total number of product that belongs to the subcategory.

my `categorymodel` looks like

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use App\Subcategory;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function subCategory(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

and my `subcategory` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subcategory';

    public $timestamps = false;


    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'subcategory_id');
    }
}
```

and finally my `product` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

}
```

however I have displayed all the sub-category names that belongs to the category by doing like this in my controller

```
 $categories = Category::with('subCategory')->get();
```

I have already achieved below result in my view.

```
category 1
  subcategory 1
  subcategory 2
  subcategory 3
category 2
  subcategory 1
  subcategory 2
  subcategory 3
```

Now i just want to count the number of products that belongs to the subcategory like for exampole

```
 category 1
      subcategory 1 (20)
      subcategory 2 (2)
      subcategory 3 (3)
    category 2
      subcategory 1 (12)
      subcategory 2 (11)
      subcategory 3 (2)
```

How can I achieve such result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = Category::with('subCategory')->get();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    echo "{$category->category_name}\n";
    foreach ($category->subCategory as $subcategory)
    {
        echo "\t{$subcategory->subcategory_name} ({$subcategory->products()->count()})\n";
    }
}
```

Just an idea. Adapt with your view code.

By the way, I think your `product` should not contain `category_id` because it already indirectly refer to its category via `subcategory_id`.